# Terracotta console not showing my application when remote

Tags: terracotta

My application uses terracotta/ehcache for hibernate 2nd level cache as well as 'custom' application caching, when running the terracotta server locally and connecting to it with the developer console I can see my application and the various caches and stats. When I deploy the same setup to a different server, it seems to be working but when I connect the developer console to the remote server, I am able to see a server in the server array under the Topology node, but I do not have a 'My Application' node as I do when running it locally. Is this correct, are you not able to see this when connecting remotely or have a messed up the configuration?

```
<tc:tc-config xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-6.xsd">

  <system>
    <configuration-model>production</configuration-model>
  </system>
  <servers>
    <server host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" name="MyWorkLife Test">
      <data>/home/mwltest/Terracotta/server-data</data>
      <logs>/home/mwltest/Terracotta/server-logs</logs>
      <index>/home/mwltest/Terracotta/server-index</index>
      <statistics>/home/mwltest/Terracotta/server-statistics</statistics>
      <dso-port bind="127.0.0.1">9510</dso-port>
      <jmx-port bind="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">9520</jmx-port>
<!--      <authentication/> -->
      <dso>
        <client-reconnect-window>120</client-reconnect-window>
        <persistence>
          <mode>permanent-store</mode>
        </persistence>
        <garbage-collection>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <interval>3600</interval>
        </garbage-collection>
      </dso>
    </server>
    <update-check>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </update-check>
  </servers>
  <clients>
    <logs>logs-%i</logs>
  </clients>

</tc:tc-config>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide verison of terracotta you use, JDK ver. and OS ver.

Comment: Using Terracotta 3.7.2, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03) (Oracle) and Ubuntu linux

Comment: I've had this issue also...when I restarted server instance it was back to normal. Also there is a newer ver. 3.7.4 (you probably get pop up about it) to try on...I suspect its a bug in the product. You should also check cache server logs to see if any abnormal activity going on.

Comment: I have upgraded to 3.7.4 and bounced the server a number of time with no change in the result? I have included my config in the original post, can you see any obvious issues?

Comment: This also happens when the version of dev console (terracotta) is of higher than that of running on remote location. In that case, "My Application" section never loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help, I have managed to get it working, it seems a little patience is the answer. It takes quite a while before the application shows up (over a minute!). Sorry if I wasted anyone's time and thanks again for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

In my case terracotta server restart did help with a similar symptoms. I have checked your configuration...nothing special there. Just in case I'm attaching my config for your reference (I use mirror group).
Also I noticed that you use `<configuration-model>production</configuration-model>` which I don't.

Try using my config (that works without issues you described), here it is:

```
<tc:tc-config xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-6.xsd" xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tc-properties>
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.timeout.millis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="sigar.enabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="search.use.commit.thread" value="false"/>
    <property name="search.lucene.use.ram.directory" value="true"/>
    <property name="search.query.wait.for.txns" value="false"/>
    <property name="logging.maxLogFileSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="logging.maxBackups" value="10"/>
  </tc-properties>
  <servers>
    <!--Sets where the Terracotta server can be found. Replace the value of host with the server's IP address.-->
    <server host="xxx.myhost.com" name="server1">
      <data>%(user.home)/terracotta/server1-data</data>
      <logs>%(user.home)/terracotta/server1-logs</logs>
      <index>%(user.home)/terracotta/server1-index</index>
      <statistics>%(user.home)/terracotta/statistics1</statistics>
      <dso>
        <client-reconnect-window>120</client-reconnect-window>
        <persistence>
          <!--<mode>permanent-store</mode>-->
          <mode>temporary-swap-only</mode>
          <!--<offheap>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <maxDataSize>450m</maxDataSize>
          </offheap>-->
        </persistence>
        <garbage-collection>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <interval>300</interval>
        </garbage-collection>
      </dso>
      <dso-port>9510</dso-port>
      <jmx-port>9520</jmx-port>
      <l2-group-port>9530</l2-group-port>
    </server>
    <server host="yyy.myhost.com" name="server2">
      <data>%(user.home)/terracotta/server2-data</data>
      <logs>%(user.home)/terracotta/server2-logs</logs>
      <index>%(user.home)/terracotta/server2-index</index>
      <statistics>%(user.home)/terracotta/statistics2</statistics>
      <dso>
        <client-reconnect-window>120</client-reconnect-window>
        <persistence>
          <!--<mode>permanent-store</mode>-->
          <mode>temporary-swap-only</mode>
          <!--<offheap>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
          <maxDataSize>450m</maxDataSize>
       </offheap>-->
        </persistence>
        <garbage-collection>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <interval>300</interval>
        </garbage-collection>
      </dso>
      <dso-port>9510</dso-port>
      <jmx-port>9520</jmx-port>
      <l2-group-port>9530</l2-group-port>
    </server>
    <mirror-groups>
      <mirror-group group-name="groupA">
        <members>
          <member>server1</member>
          <member>server2</member>
        </members>
        <ha>
          <mode>networked-active-passive</mode>
          <networked-active-passive>
            <election-time>5</election-time>
          </networked-active-passive>
        </ha>
      </mirror-group>
    </mirror-groups>
  </servers>
  <clients>
    <!--<logs>%(user.home)/terracotta/client-logs/%D</logs>-->
    <logs>%(user.home)/terracotta/client-logs/logs-%i.%D</logs>
  </clients>
</tc:tc-config>
```